# await client.load_extension() gives await error with NoneType

Tags: python, discord.py

```
async def load_extensions():
    for filename in os.listdir("./cogs"):
        if filename.endswith(".py"):
            # cut off the .py from the file name
            await client.load_extension(f"cogs.{filename[:-3]}")

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Bot is Online")
    await client.change_presence(activity = discord.Game(name = "Just Came Online!"))


async def main():
    await load_extensions()
    

asyncio.run(main())
```

When Running this I get an error `await client.load_extension(f"cogs.{filename[:-3]}") TypeError: object NoneType can't be used in 'await' expression`

No idea what I have done wrong here and any help on how to fix this would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Edit: Some basic information that I probably should have included.

- `os.listdir("./cogs")` does return the correct names of the files.
- I just updated to python 3.9 after checking that it recommended the update
- I am using discord.py version 1.7.3

Update:
I am trying to host this bot on heroku and get this response

`File "/app/bot.py",lineno 3 client.load_extension(f"cogs.{filename[:-3]}")`

Comment: load_extension() is a normal function, not an asynchronous one.  You cannot "await" it.

Comment: @FrankYellin Just a note that `load_extension` is a coroutine in 2.0, but the asker is using 1.7.3 so that is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay. So I realized that Heroku was trying to use Discord.py version 2 because I didn't tell it not to in my requirements.txt file. Once I updated to discord.py 2.0 as well as converted to using python 3.9 it fixed my issues as I was able to use the proper commands for the async cog coroutine.